File removed from .deb package
I created a .deb file where I originally stored an F file. Then I installed this deb file and the F file is correctly in place under a D directory. Then I rebuilt the .deb file excluding the F file from its building. Now I would like to install this new .deb file forbidding apt to remove the installed F file from the D directory. Is it possible?

If files are mananged by a package, then there is NO guarantee that those files aren't removed if the file is gone from a package.

The file is owned by the old version of the package, so when it goes through the removal process as part of the upgrade, that file will be removed (unless it is a conffile) - the new version's file list isn't going to affect that

The only way to achieve that is to list the file in the conffiles file.
All other files are deleted when the updated package is installed.
